# Return table from stored procedure / function after doing merge function SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that takes one table, and doing merge to another table. I want to get a table of logs with the data of what happened to each row, without inserting the data to a table.

I understand a stored procedure cannot return a table, and therefore I thought about using a function, but as of my understanding a function can not make transformations on tables.

Is combining a stored procedure with a function the solution? Or is there any thing else that I am not aware of?

Comment: `MERGE`, like the other DML statements, supports `OUTPUT`, have you considered using that?

Comment: *"I understand store procedure cannot return a table"* if by this you mean `RETURN`, no, but then the `RETURN` operator is meant to be used to denote the success of a stored procedure, not a data value. `0` means success and anything else means failure. If you want to provide scalar values back in a Procedure you use `OUTPUT` parameters, if you want provide a dataset you would `SELECT` it (or`OUTPUT` (clause) it in this case).

Comment: Is the data being passed back to another procedure or to the application?  If to the the application, then it can handle the OUPUT clause output like any other select.  If to another procedure, then it's more difficult and has to be saved at least temporarily.  If you only want a log value, not a table record, then perhaps convert the output to a single XML value and pass it back via a output parameter.  The requirements are not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stored procedure can certainly return a result set, which the client can consume directly just like a regular `SELECT` statement.

That said, there are a range of options, none of which are perfect. Each suits a different scenario, and are described at length by Erland Sommarskog in [How to Share Data between Stored Procedures](http://sommarskog.se/share_data.html):

> - Table-valued Functions
> - Inline Functions
> - Multi-statement Functions
> - Using a Table
> - Sharing a Temp Table
> - Process-keyed Table
> - `INSERT-EXEC`
> - Using SQLCLR
> - `OPENQUERY`
> - XML
> - Cursor Variables

For example, you may not wish to use a permanent table, but a temporary table created by the client and populated by the stored procedure can work well, if directly consuming the results of a `SELECT` inside the procedure is not suitable.